# SQL: select over two tables

Tags: sql

I have an SQL problem i was wondering if someone could help me out. Below is the schema of the database

### Player

- playerid (primary key)
- playerName

### PlaysAt

- clubId (primary key)
- playerId (fk to PLAYER.playerid)
- yearsAtClub

My question is how do i select the clubId of the club where player named john and stephen play where john and stephen play at the same club. I have no idea how to get the club id in this case. i have managed to get the join part correct as im able to select the club id of john but cant get it when i specify the both players using WHERE playerName = john AND playerName = stephen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
  SELECT c.clubid
    FROM PLAYSAT c
    JOIN PLAYER p ON p.playerid = c.playerid
   WHERE p.playername IN ('john', 'stephen')
GROUP BY c.clubid
  HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p.playername) = 2
```

The key is that the number of parameters in the IN clause needs to match the COUNT in the HAVING clause -- in this case, two.

The DISTINCT helps in case there isn't a primary key or unique constraint on ***both*** the `PLAYSAT.clubid` and `PLAYSAT.playerid` columns -- two entries for "John" otherwise would be considered valid if for the same clubid value.  Otherwise, the DISTINCT can be omitted from the query.

Answer (score 1):

You can join twice to the same table by using the keyword `as` to create aliases:

```
select clubId
from PlaysAt
join Player as Player1 using (playerId)
join Player as Player2 using (playerId)
where Player1.playerName = 'john'
and Player2.playerName = 'stephen';
```

This assumes that the table Player has the primary key `playerId` (with a capital "I"). It doesn't in your code, but I couldn't tell if this was a typo. If you use the same name for primary key and foreign key you can take advantage of the `using` keyword, which makes queries much simpler.